# findContainingViewHolder returns null

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception

In the following application, you have basically 2 fragments: 1) a food database, 2) a consumed food list

1) the user can manually add foods with the corresponding macronutrient information (kcal, carbs, protein, etc.). The data is stored in a SQL database via Room and is being observed via LiveData

2) a fragment (FoodDiaryFragment.kt) that shows the "consumed" food via a recyclerView. The user can add foods by tapping on a FAB which sends the user to another fragment (AddConsumedFoodFragment.kt). 
this shows a spinner and a form. The spinner shows a list of the foods from the food database (from 1). In the form the user can just enter one value (how much gram of the selected food has been consumed). 
This data is also added to the same SQL database in a table with: id (autogenerated), amount (entered by the user), consumedFood (selected from the spinner and connected to the other table via a foreign key) and consumedDate (autogenerated date at the moment when the item is added).

The recycler view (2) shows the items with additional information which are calculated in the RecyclerViewAdapter (basically multiplying the amount and the corresponding macronutrient info [kcal, carbs, etc.], see getDailyValues() in the adapter) and also "groups" the items by date. This means, for each day a separate viewHolder (DateViewHolder) which displays the day (and the sum of each macro) is being added to the recyclerView (see sortAndGroupFood() in FoodDiaryFragment.kt)

[image: DateViewHolder and ConsumedFoodViewHolder]

As I am using RecyclerView Selection setStableIds() (see init block) is set to true. StableIdKeyProvider.java adds an ChildAttachStateChangeListener with the onChilViewDetachedFromWindows() function.

I am not sure exactly when this function (I would love an explanation) is called but this seems to happen sometimes, when either an Item is deleted (items can be deleted via RecyclerView.Selection) or an item is added. The app crashes with the below shown NullPointerException. When the app is restarted the action that eventually ended in the crash has been conducted successfully.

I am really desperate and have tried to figure out why a null view is passed to this function for several hours now, but obviously I have not been succesful.

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView#findcontainingviewholder) findContainingViewHolder returns null if the provided view is not a descendant of that RecyclerView

Question: What problem causes the return of null and how can I precent it?
[GitHub Depo Link](https://github.com/hunnihundert/MacroTracker/tree/develop)

**FoodDiaryFragment.kt**

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.*
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.recyclerview.selection.*
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.hooni.macrotracker.R
import com.hooni.macrotracker.adapter.ConsumedFoodRecyclerViewAdapter
import com.hooni.macrotracker.data.ConsumedFood
import com.hooni.macrotracker.recyclerviewselector.ConsumedFoodItemDetailsLookup
import com.hooni.macrotracker.viewmodels.FoodViewModel
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_food_diary.view.*
import java.text.DateFormat
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat



class FoodDiaryFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var foodViewModel: FoodViewModel
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var adapter: ConsumedFoodRecyclerViewAdapter

    private val dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance()

    var tracker: SelectionTracker<Long>? = null
    var actionMode: ActionMode? = null


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_food_diary, container, false)
        initRecyclerView(v)
        initViewModel()
        initButtons(v)
        // this makes sure, that in case the last destination was addConsumedFoodFragment
        // the 'back' button doesn't bring you back to the addConsumedFoodFragment, but to the one that
        // has been visited before
        findNavController().popBackStack(R.id.addConsumedFoodFragment, true)
        return v
    }

    private fun initButtons(v: View) {
        val addNewFood = v.addNewConsumedFood
        addNewFood.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_diaryFragment_to_addConsumedFoodFragment)
        }
    }

    private fun initRecyclerView(view: View) {
        recyclerView = view.food_diary_recyclerView
        adapter = ConsumedFoodRecyclerViewAdapter()
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)

        tracker = SelectionTracker.Builder<Long>(
            "selectedItemsConsumedFoo",
            recyclerView,
            StableIdKeyProvider(recyclerView),
            ConsumedFoodItemDetailsLookup(recyclerView),
            StorageStrategy.createLongStorage()
        ).withSelectionPredicate(
            SelectionPredicates.createSelectAnything()
        ).build()

        val actionModeCallBack = object : ActionMode.Callback {
            override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
                val inflater = mode?.menuInflater
                actionMode = mode
                actionMode?.title = getString(R.string.delete)
                inflater?.inflate(R.menu.action_menu, menu)
                return true
            }

            override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode?, item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
                return when (item?.itemId) {
                    R.id.action_menu_delete -> {
                        removeItems(tracker?.selection!!)
                        tracker?.clearSelection()
                        actionMode?.finish()
                        actionMode = null
                        return true
                    }
                    else -> false
                }
            }

            override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode?) {
                tracker?.clearSelection()
                actionMode?.finish()
                actionMode = null
            }
        }

        tracker?.addObserver(
            object : SelectionTracker.SelectionObserver<Long>() {

                override fun onSelectionChanged() {
                    if (tracker?.selection!!.size() > 0) {
                        if (actionMode == null) activity?.startActionMode(actionModeCallBack)
                    } else {
                        actionMode?.finish()
                        actionMode = null
                    }
                }
            }
        )
        adapter.tracker = tracker
    }

    private fun removeItems(selection: Selection<Long>) {
        val foodsToDelete = adapter.getFood(selection)
        foodsToDelete.forEach {
            foodViewModel.deleteConsumedFood(it)
        }
    }


    private fun initViewModel() {
        foodViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(FoodViewModel::class.java)
        foodViewModel.allConsumedFood.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { consumedFoodList ->
            consumedFoodList?.let { adapter.setConsumedFood(sortAndGroupFood(consumedFoodList)) }
        })
        foodViewModel.allFood.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { food ->
            food?.let { adapter.setFood(food.sortedBy {it.foodName}) }
        })
    }

    private fun sortAndGroupFood(consumedFoodList: List<ConsumedFood>): List<ConsumedFood> {
        val sortedList = consumedFoodList.sortedBy{it.consumedDate}
        val groupedMap: Map<String,List<ConsumedFood>> = sortedList.groupBy { dateFormat.format(it.consumedDate)}
        val finalizedList = mutableListOf<ConsumedFood>()

        groupedMap.forEach {
            finalizedList.add(createDateHeader(it.key))
            finalizedList.addAll(it.value)
        }
        return finalizedList.toList()
    }

    private fun createDateHeader(dateString: String): ConsumedFood {
        val date = dateFormat.parse(dateString)
        return ConsumedFood(null,-1,"DATE_HEADER",date!!)
    }

}
```

**AddFoodFragment.kt**

```
package com.hooni.macrotracker.fragments

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.InputType
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
import com.hooni.macrotracker.R
import com.hooni.macrotracker.data.Food
import com.hooni.macrotracker.util.Tools
import com.hooni.macrotracker.viewmodels.FoodViewModel
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_add_food.view.*
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols
import java.util.*

class AddFoodFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var foodViewModel: FoodViewModel

    private lateinit var enterTextFoodName: TextInputLayout
    private lateinit var enterTextKcal: TextInputLayout
    private lateinit var enterTextCarbs: TextInputLayout
    private lateinit var enterTextProtein: TextInputLayout
    private lateinit var enterTextFat: TextInputLayout



    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_food, container, false)
        initButtons(v)
        initViewModel()
        initTextInPutLayouts(v)
        return v
    }

    private fun initTextInPutLayouts(v: View) {

        enterTextFoodName = v.enter_food_name
        enterTextKcal = v.enter_kcal
        enterTextCarbs = v.enter_carbs
        enterTextProtein = v.enter_protein
        enterTextFat = v.enter_fat

        enterTextCarbs.setNumberDecimalInputOnly()
        enterTextProtein.setNumberDecimalInputOnly()
        enterTextFat.setNumberDecimalInputOnly()


    }

    private fun initButtons(view: View) {
        view.cancel_add_food.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_addFoodFragment_to_foodListFragment)
            Tools.hideSoftKeyboard(view, context)
        }

        view.add_food.setOnClickListener {
            if (validateValues()) {
                val newFood = createNewFood()
                foodViewModel.insertFood(newFood)
                showSuccessfulAdd()
                view.cancel_add_food.performClick()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun validateValues(): Boolean {

        val isFoodNameValid = enterTextFoodName.validateInput { it != null }
        val isKcalValid = enterTextKcal.validateInput { it?.toIntOrNull() != null }
        val isCarbsValid = enterTextCarbs.validateInput { it?.toDoubleOrNull() != null }
        val isProteinValid = enterTextProtein.validateInput { it?.toDoubleOrNull() != null }
        val isFatValid = enterTextFat.validateInput { it?.toDoubleOrNull() != null }


        return (isFoodNameValid
                && isKcalValid
                && isCarbsValid
                && isProteinValid
                && isFatValid)

    }

    private fun initViewModel() {
        foodViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(FoodViewModel::class.java)
    }


    private fun createNewFood(): Food {
        val foodName =
            enterTextFoodName.editText?.text.toString().trim()
        val kcal =
            enterTextKcal.editText?.text.toString().trim().toInt()
        val carbs =
            enterTextCarbs.editText?.text.toString().replaceDecimalSeparator().toDouble()
        val protein =
            enterTextProtein.editText?.text.toString().replaceDecimalSeparator().toDouble()
        val fat = enterTextFat.editText?.text.toString().replaceDecimalSeparator().toDouble()
        return Food(foodName, kcal, carbs.round(), fat.round(), protein.round())
    }


    private fun showSuccessfulAdd() {
        Toast.makeText(
            activity,
            "${enterTextFoodName.editText?.text.toString().trim()} added to database",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()
    }



    private inline fun TextInputLayout.validateInput(validate: (String?) -> Boolean): Boolean {

        val textToValidate = this.editText?.text.toString().replaceDecimalSeparator().trim()
        when {
            textToValidate.isEmpty() -> {
                error = getString(R.string.cant_be_empty)

            }
            !validate(textToValidate) -> {
                error = getString(R.string.invalid_value)
            }
            else -> {
                error = null
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }


    private fun TextInputLayout.setNumberDecimalInputOnly() {
        this.editText?.apply {
            inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER or InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL
        }
    }

    private fun Double.round(decimals: Int = 1): Double = "%.${decimals}f".format(Locale.US,this).toDouble()


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private fun String.replaceDecimalSeparator(): String {
        val decimalSeparator = when(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
            in Int.MIN_VALUE..Build.VERSION_CODES.M -> {DecimalFormatSymbols(resources.configuration.locale).decimalSeparator}
            else -> DecimalFormatSymbols(resources.configuration.locales[0]).decimalSeparator
        }
        return this.replace(decimalSeparator, '.')
    }

}
```

**ConsumedFoodRecyclerViewAdapter.kt**

```
package com.hooni.macrotracker.adapter

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.selection.ItemDetailsLookup
import androidx.recyclerview.selection.Selection
import androidx.recyclerview.selection.SelectionTracker
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.hooni.macrotracker.R
import com.hooni.macrotracker.data.ConsumedFood
import com.hooni.macrotracker.data.Food
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_food_diary_date_list_item.view.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_food_diary_list_item.view.*
import java.text.DateFormat
import java.util.*


private const val DATE_VIEW_HOLDER = 0
private const val CONSUMED_FOOD_VIEW_HOLDER = 1

class ConsumedFoodRecyclerViewAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<ConsumedFoodRecyclerViewAdapter.BaseViewHolder<*>>() {

    private var mConsumedFoodList = emptyList<ConsumedFood>()
    private var mFoodList = emptyList<Food>()
    var tracker: SelectionTracker<Long>? = null

    init {
        setHasStableIds(true)
    }

    abstract class BaseViewHolder<T>(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        abstract fun getItemDetails(): ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails<Long>
    }


    inner class ConsumedFoodViewHolder(mView: View) :BaseViewHolder<ConsumedFood>(mView) {
        private val mConsumedFoodName: TextView = mView.consumed_food_name
        private val mConsumedKcal: TextView = mView.consumed_kcal
        private val mConsumedAmount: TextView = mView.consumed_amount
        private val mConsumedCarbs: TextView = mView.consumed_carb_amount
        private val mConsumedProtein: TextView = mView.consumed_protein_amount
        private val mConsumedFat: TextView = mView.consumed_fat_amount


        override fun getItemDetails(): ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails<Long> =
            object : ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails<Long>() {
                override fun getSelectionKey(): Long? = itemId
                override fun getPosition(): Int = adapterPosition
            }

        fun bind(isActivated: Boolean = false, item: ConsumedFood) {
            val consumedMacroOfFood = calculateConsumedMacro(item.amount,item.consumedFood)
            itemView.isActivated = isActivated
            mConsumedFoodName.text = item.consumedFood
            mConsumedKcal.text =  itemView.context.getString(R.string.list_item_kcal,consumedMacroOfFood[0].toInt())
            mConsumedAmount.text = itemView.context.getString(R.string.list_item_amount,item.amount)
            mConsumedCarbs.text = itemView.context.getString(R.string.list_item_macro,consumedMacroOfFood[1])
            mConsumedProtein.text = itemView.context.getString(R.string.list_item_macro,consumedMacroOfFood[2])
            mConsumedFat.text = itemView.context.getString(R.string.list_item_macro,consumedMacroOfFood[3])
        }

    }

    inner class DateViewHolder(mView: View): BaseViewHolder<ConsumedFood>(mView) {
        private val mConsumedDate: TextView = mView.food_diary_date
        private val mTotalConsumedDayKcal: TextView = mView.food_diary_date_sum_kcal
        private val mTotalConsumedDayCarbs: TextView = mView.food_diary_date_sum_carbs
        private val mTotalConsumedDayProtein: TextView = mView.food_diary_date_sum_protein
        private val mTotalConsumedDayFat: TextView = mView.food_diary_date_sum_fat

        override fun getItemDetails(): ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails<Long> =
            object : ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails<Long>() {
                override fun getSelectionKey(): Long? = itemId
                override fun getPosition(): Int = adapterPosition
            }

        fun bind(item: ConsumedFood) {
            mConsumedDate.text = itemView.context
                .getString(R.string.list_item_date,DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM,DateFormat.getAvailableLocales()[0]).format(item.consumedDate))
            mTotalConsumedDayKcal.text = itemView.context.getString(R.string.list_item_kcal,getDailyValues(item.consumedDate)[0].toInt())
            mTotalConsumedDayCarbs.text = itemView.context.getString(R.string.list_item_macro,getDailyValues(item.consumedDate)[1])
            mTotalConsumedDayProtein.text = itemView.context.getString(R.string.list_item_macro,getDailyValues(item.consumedDate)[2])
            mTotalConsumedDayFat.text = itemView.context.getString(R.string.list_item_macro,getDailyValues(item.consumedDate)[3])
        }
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return if(mConsumedFoodList[position].amount < 0) {
            DATE_VIEW_HOLDER
        } else CONSUMED_FOOD_VIEW_HOLDER
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BaseViewHolder<ConsumedFood> {
        return when(viewType) {
            DATE_VIEW_HOLDER -> {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.fragment_food_diary_date_list_item,parent,false)
                DateViewHolder(view)
            }
            //CONSUMED_FOOD_VIEW_HOLDER
            else -> {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.fragment_food_diary_list_item,parent,false)
                ConsumedFoodViewHolder(view)
            }

        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = mConsumedFoodList.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BaseViewHolder<*>, position: Int) {

        when(holder) {
            is DateViewHolder -> {
                tracker?.let {
                    holder.bind(mConsumedFoodList[position])
                }
            }
            is ConsumedFoodViewHolder -> {
                tracker?.let {
                    holder.bind(it.isSelected(position.toLong()),mConsumedFoodList[position])
                }
            }
        }

    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long = position.toLong()

    internal fun getFood(ids: Selection<Long>): List<ConsumedFood> {
        val foodsToDelete: MutableList<ConsumedFood> = mutableListOf()
        ids.forEach {
            foodsToDelete.add(mConsumedFoodList[it.toInt()])
        }
        return foodsToDelete.toList()
    }

    internal fun setConsumedFood(consumedFood: List<ConsumedFood>) {
        mConsumedFoodList = consumedFood
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    internal fun setFood(food: List<Food>) {
        mFoodList = food
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }


    private fun calculateConsumedMacro(amount: Int, food: String): List<Double>{
        val kcalOfTheFood = mFoodList.firstOrNull{ it.foodName == food}?.kcal?.toDouble() ?: 0.0
        val carbsOfTheFood = mFoodList.firstOrNull{ it.foodName == food}?.carbs ?: 0.0
        val proteinOfTheFood = mFoodList.firstOrNull{ it.foodName == food}?.protein ?: 0.0
        val fatOfTheFood = mFoodList.firstOrNull{ it.foodName == food}?.fat ?: 0.0
        return listOf(kcalOfTheFood.getAmountOfMacro(amount),
            carbsOfTheFood.getAmountOfMacro(amount),
            proteinOfTheFood.getAmountOfMacro(amount),
            fatOfTheFood.getAmountOfMacro(amount))
    }


    private fun Double.getAmountOfMacro(amount: Int): Double {
        return this * amount / 100
    }

    private fun getDailyValues(day: Date): List<Double> {
        val foodsOfSameDay = mConsumedFoodList.filter{ DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(it.consumedDate) == DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(day)}
        val macrosOfSameDay = mutableListOf<List<Double>>()
        foodsOfSameDay.forEach {macrosOfSameDay.add(calculateConsumedMacro(it.amount,it.consumedFood))}

        val sumKcal = macrosOfSameDay.sumByDouble { it[0] }
        val sumCarbs = macrosOfSameDay.sumByDouble { it[1] }
        val sumProtein = macrosOfSameDay.sumByDouble { it[2] }
        val sumFat = macrosOfSameDay.sumByDouble { it[3] }

        return listOf(sumKcal,sumCarbs,sumProtein,sumFat)
    }

}
```

**Error**

```
2020-02-18 18:34:07.287 28614-28614/com.hooni.macrotracker E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.hooni.macrotracker, PID: 28614
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()' on a null object reference
        at androidx.recyclerview.selection.StableIdKeyProvider.onDetached(StableIdKeyProvider.java:90)
        at androidx.recyclerview.selection.StableIdKeyProvider$1.onChildViewDetachedFromWindow(StableIdKeyProvider.java:69)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchChildDetached(RecyclerView.java:7546)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.removeDetachedView(RecyclerView.java:4349)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getScrapOrCachedViewForId(RecyclerView.java:6738)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6189)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1915)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1915)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:753)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2792)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2319)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1460)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7183)
2020-02-18 18:34:07.288 28614-28614/com.hooni.macrotracker E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

when adding a new item to the recyclerView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is related to the SelectrionTracker (RecyclerView Selection, which was just briefly mentioned) and it's StableIdKeyProvider.

So... apparently this crash happens, when the StableIdKeyProvider is trying to removed/replaced the stable id while the item (cardview) is no longer attached to the ViewHolder (DateViewHolder or ConsumedFoodViewHolder).

Honestly, I still do not understand the logic behind that, but once I will, I will come back and update this post.

The solution is to provide a custom KeyProvider like the following one:

```
class ConsumedFoodListItemKeyProvider(private val recyclerView: RecyclerView) : ItemKeyProvider<Long>(ItemKeyProvider.SCOPE_MAPPED) {
    override fun getKey(position: Int): Long? {
        return recyclerView.adapter?.getItemId(position)
    }

    override fun getPosition(key: Long): Int {
        val viewHolder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForItemId(key)
        return viewHolder?.layoutPosition ?: RecyclerView.NO_POSITION
    }
}
```

and use it in the SelectionTracker.Builder